# Installed Node v18.15.0 installed but Error in running ironfish

Tags: node.js

Problem in running ironfish

NodeJS version 16.20.0 is not compatible. Must have Node v18 installed:

https://nodejs.org/en/download/
After v18 is installed, MAKE SURE TO run `npm install -g ironfish` again to install ironfish with the correct Node version

Already have
node -v -> v18.15.0 Installed
Ironfish Installed

My-MacBook:~ USER$ ironfish
NodeJS version 16.20.0 is not compatible. Must have Node v18 installed: https://nodejs.org/en/download/
After v18 is installed, MAKE SURE TO run `npm install -g ironfish` again to install ironfish with the correct Node version
My-MacBook:~ USER$ node -v
v18.15.0